# How do I store heroku config variables for use with foreman?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, foreman

I deploy on heroku and use foreman to manage our different servers.

I have a variety of environment variables that are used on Heroko for things like S3 config parameters.

How do I configure them? I've set them manually using heroku's `heroku config:set` command, but foreman also supports using `.env` file. But if I use an `.env`` file, should I check them in? If not, how do I maintain them on heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also a [Heroku Config plugin](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-config) for the Heroku CLI that provides a way for you to push/pull your Heroku environment to use locally.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding your .env file to your .gitignore so it's not committed to git. Maybe leave a sample of it there so other devs know what they need to set when they pull the code fresh.

You can manage them via the `heroku config` command as you've already done or write a script that iterates your .env file and sets them on your heroku app - provided they are for the correct environment of course.

Answer (score 0):

Another good option:
Kenneth Reitz created a tool for that purpose called [autoenv](https://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv), and he wrote this [cookbook](https://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv/wiki/Cookbook).